# serving a classification model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to build a classifier in tensorflow, I have written the model and tested it to see it work but would like to build it for production,
but cant seem to find a way to pass input into the model 
this is my code i used to train and test

```
#training the neural netork
def get_train_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(tr_features)
    y = tf.constant(tr_labels)
    return x, y

# fit the model using 1000 training steps
classifier.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=1000)

#testing the neural network
def get_test_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(ts_features)
    y = tf.constant(ts_labels)
    return x, y

#Calculate accuracy 
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_test_inputs, steps=1000)["accuracy"]
print('Test accuracy : ', format(accuracy_score))
```

i have tested it by passing test data to the predict_classes function and that works, my question is how do i build a builder for this, so i can pass in data from external application?

```
#test to test prediction
def new_sample():
    return np.array(testing,dtype=np.float32)

predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=new_sample))
print('predition : ', format(predictions))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would to suggest to do an implementation much like 
[ex.](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/eval.py)
This is fairly similar to what you want to do. Though you would need to implement [checkpoints](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) (Crtl+f checkpoint file). Much of the code there is specific to his/her program, but the gist of it is to create a file "eval.py" which runs a net off of a previous saved checkpoint. In the eval.py file, you can input whatever file you wish with your input.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is [TensorflowServing](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/)

Comment: I have implemented that code but it doesnt to work, how do i pass the input to be used in predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=new_sample)) ?